# jQuery how to append multiple img srcs into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My jQuery/JS is setup so that on doc load it looks for all the img srcs and pushes them into an array:

```
var sliderImg = [];
sliderImg.push($('.thumbnail').children('img').attr('src'));
```

I then have code to alert the array on a click event:

```
$('.thumbnail').each(function() {
$(this).click(function() {
    alert(sliderImg);
});
});
```

However, it's only adding the first img src path, is there away to add all of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each`;

```
$('.thumbnail').children('img').each(function() {
  sliderImg.push($(this).attr('src');
});
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to take the html instead of just one of it's attributes? The .html() does not seem to return anything!

Comment: well, if parent of img element isn't suitable for this, you could use this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/keune/ypdyw60k/ just change the `$(#x)` selector with `$(this)`

Comment: Cheers Keune, set me on the right path - just needed to wrap src in img html: sliderImg.push('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />');

Comment: You could also use map()

Answer (score 2):

[`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method, when used as getter, returns the attribute of the first element in the set. If you need an array of all attributes, you have to loop over all elements. You can use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method or more convenient [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var sliderImg = $('.thumbnail').children('img').map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [`.attr()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of matched elements

So `$('.thumbnail').children('img').attr('src')` only return the source of the first image.

You can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate the images and push the sources one by one:

```
var sliderImg = [];
$('.thumbnail').children('img').each(function() {
    sliderImg.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
```